# move my global .gitconfig file

Tags: git, windows-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing .gitconfig location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050905/changing-gitconfig-location)

I am a bit of a git newb so I am sure this must be simple, just eluding me.

On my work laptop my `%homedrive%` and `%homepath%` are set to a network home share. By default git is looking there for my `.gitconfig` file. This is no good for when I take my laptop anywhere, gitbash takes forever to start and of course my username etc are unset.

What I would like to do is to specify my actual local home path as the location for it (`c:\Users\Tim\`) but leave my `%homedrive%\%homepath%` alone.

How do I do this?

Comment: This discussion may help. http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/issues/detail?id=497

Comment: interesting I don't see the problem that they do, I guess I have the newer version. But no solution for my issue there.

Answer (score 8):

OK. Seems that the fix (for my purposes) is to create a system environment variable HOME and set that to my C:\Users\Tim path.

Comment: It might worth adding that if you run git config --global to add an item to your config that your symlink will be overwritten with actual copy of the .gitconfig that is being used. I ran into this issue when testing a location where \PathForNewLocationOfConfig.gitconfig was my Dropbox folder