# The environment variable HOME is not set

Tags: environment-variables

I searched here for a guide to set environment variables and found

[Eclipse project-wide error: Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175089/eclipse-project-wide-error-warning-the-environment-variable-home-is-not-set-t)

An answer suggests to type "environment" at the start menu.
The "edit_environment_variables" entry from the query is a .png .
So, I can not apply the next step "Click the "New" button.
", because it is an image. What went wrong here? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Did you actually type "environment" in the start menu? There is no reason that should yield a PNG image. Did you type it into an internet search?

Comment: yes I typed it into the start menu. I did not type it into any Internet search. But the problem is solved now. If I remember correctly setting path variables was possible via (sorry I have German version) Systemsteuerung>System>Erweiterte Systemeinstellungen>Umgebungsvariablen. I Hope this works for environmental variables as well. Else I still have no idea^^ But thank you anyway for the answer