# Eclipse message warning : the environment variable home is not set

Tags: eclipse, java-home

I started Eclipse and got below error. I set the variable system JAVA_HOME with the java path up to bin as value but it still doesn't work what should I do?  HELP PLEASE.

Warning:

> The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will
>   be used to store the Git user global configuration and to define the
>   default location to store repositories: 'C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Wizard'. If this is not correct please set the HOME
>   environment variable and restart Eclipse. Otherwise Git for Windows
>   and EGit might behave differently since they see different
>   configuration options.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse project-wide error: Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175089/eclipse-project-wide-error-warning-the-environment-variable-home-is-not-set-t)

Answer (score 0):

I think this has already been answered here:

[Eclipse project-wide error: Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175089/eclipse-project-wide-error-warning-the-environment-variable-home-is-not-set-t?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: You have literally cut and pasted your answer from someone else's answer to another SO post. If you think another SO question/answer is relevant you should just link to that in a comment to the OP, you shouldn't replicate their answer here. (Apart from that, there were several alternative answers provided to that other question.)

Comment: yes, I have added the link as well as the copy/pasted the answer. If thats against the forum rules, I will remove that.

Comment: That's better. Thanks.