# Gitlab and Katalon Studio - Source Git repository is empty

Tags: automated-tests, gitlab, katalon-studio

My disk died.

Remote `Katalon Studio` repository is setup with `Gitlab`. I am able to reach the repo via web browser, but when trying to clone repository with `Katalon Studio`, after being promped for login information twice but with no error messages, I receive the "Source Git repository is empty" message.

How can I access my data from `Katalon`?

Comment: Based on the katalon page : https://docs.katalon.com/display/KD/Git+Integration. It's just a remote git repository. Where does GitLab come into it? Have you had a look at [working with remotes](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. In the end, searching through the logs, I found this message:

"!MESSAGE Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git
user global configuration and to define the default location to store repositories:..."

So I found an answer here:
[Eclipse project-wide error: Warning: The environment variable HOME is not set. The following directory will be used to store the Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19175089/eclipse-project-wide-error-warning-the-environment-variable-home-is-not-set-t).