# git ~/.config/git/config not reading

Tags: git, configuration

I had the file:

```
~/.gitconfig
```

working ok, but I decided to move it to:

```
~/.config/git/config
```

Now, `git config --global -l` just gives:

```
$ git config --global -l
fatal: unable to read config file '/home/user/.gitconfig': No such file or directory
```

I have `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` configured and exported, as well as `$HOME`. What would be the problem?

Is there some configuration I can set to `/etc/gitconfig` to make git aware of the new configuration file location (something like `core.globalconfig=$HOME/.config/git/config`)?

Thanks

--

PS. 
System: Debian Linux Wheezy

Reference:

[git config](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config/)

Comment: Just tried `[core] path = /home/user/.config/git/config` to no avail.

Comment: Try creating a symlink `~/.gitconfig` that points to `~/.config/git/config`.

Comment: That would also do, Jubobs! Thanks for the tip.

Comment: For anyone who reads, I'm still hoping there is a better answer than mine bellow. Maybe I need to check if the environment variables is really ok? A better question is: why git is not checking `$HOME/.config/git/config`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing .gitconfig location](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050905/changing-gitconfig-location)

Comment: After reading the question you pointed out, I saw that there is no better solution for windows. For linux, even that X Desktop Group has standard XDG* variables, it looks like git doesn't give a penny. So I'm accepting the answer I research, with no more hopes, unless a next version of GIT changes things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, after reading this [question about including files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1557183/is-it-possible-to-include-a-file-in-your-gitconfig/), I came up with this simple solution to make git aware of the configuration file in a different directory:

Add this line to your system file (`/etc/gitconfig`)

```
[include]
     path = $HOME/.config/git/config
```

Command:

```
sudo git config --system include.path '$HOME/.config/git/config'
```

And voilá!

--
Edited:

This solution makes `git config -l` works, but still `git config --global -l` does not work.

A workaround (from @Jubobs comment) would be create a symbolic link:

```
ln -s ~/.config/git/config .gitconfig
```

But that would still leave the .gitconfig file in the $HOME.

There must be a better solution.

Comment: Actually, @Jubobs , your comment is better than my answer. For one: `git config --global -l` still gives error. But `git config -l` now works.