# MinTTY Terminal Customization with .minttyrc

Tags: linux, cygwin, mintty

As you know, you can customize the Cygwin terminal by editing .minttyrc. I only use windows and when I first encountered and used Linux I immediately fell in love with the terminal. I have used Ubuntu (bee box for web testing) and Kali Linux (Debian - gnome desktop) for pen testing. I absolutely love the "Tango" color scheme (default in Kali Terminal) and would love to find out how you can make it look like the Kali Terminal. I am pretty much a complete noob in Linux (I only really know how to use kali tools and some basic commands)

Thank you very much!

Comment: There are several options that can be configured via the `.minttyrc`. For example, see https://www.rafaelhart.com/2015/07/minttyrc-colour-schemes-fonts-2015/. I'm not sure if you'll be able to get close to the look and feel of the Kali Terminal, but there is some customizability there.

Comment: A couple of options I've set in my `.minttyrc` that are not shown in the URL I just linked to are `CursorType` (set mine to `block`) and `CursorBlinks` (set mine to `no`).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't even know you could edit to make it remove scrollbars

Comment: Haha. I finally found the official documentation on the `.minttyrc`; it's in the `mintty` man page, logically. I don't have to rely on random blogs anymore! https://mintty.github.io/mintty.1.html#CONFIGURATION.

Answer (score 0):

I found this Q&A while I was looking for an answer why mintty won't read pick up any of the options I put in the `.minttyrc` file placed in my Windows home directory. After investigation I found that $HOME on Windows was set to a network share (somehow derived from corporate setting for %HOMEDRIVE%) and I found the corresponding file there. Modifing this file worked. I hope this helps anyone who is stuck in a similar situation.

Edit: And after making a mistake I found the right answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32233667/2010467