# Why Does Git Put .gitconfig on Network Drive?

Tags: git

I recently installed Git for Windows (https://git-scm.com/download/win) on my machine and was having issues finding my global .gitconfig file (see stackoverflow.com/questions/39670247/cant-find-global-gitconfig-file/39671485).

Turns out it was on a share/network drive. Why would Git put the global .gitconfig file there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be defined by environment HOME, which, as far as I understand, may be defined by windows domain settings to point to some "your" place in network. It is possible to redefine it in "environment for this user" settings dialog

Comment: Hi, I found this link which talks about the HOME variable http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32232978/change-the-location-of-directory-in-a-windows-install-of-git-bash. In my case, I didn't have a HOME environment variable set so it defaulted to my network drive. After setting HOME to my local drive (and moving the files from the network drive) all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was doing the same thing. I couldn't find any setting in git that would point it to a network drive - very strange.

The network drive git was looking on (in my case a P: drive) wasn't always available, so as suggested, I create a HOME environment variable and pointed it to C:\config. I then placed my .gitconfig file in there. It seems to work fine now.

I still have no explanation why it was looking at P: in the first place, perhaps there is another environment variable it was looking at, but I couldn't see anything obvious.