# Change path of ~ in bash on Windows

Tags: windows, bash

I just installed `bash.exe` on a machine running Windows 10, and it works great except I can't seem to get `~` to point to where I want it (as in `cd ~`). It automatically points to `C:`.

How can I change this to reference `C:\Users\name` where all my commonly used files are located?

I've tried setting `$HOME` to the address that I want (using `export HOME='C:\Users\name'`), but that didn't work. `echo ~` still returns `C:`

Any thoughts?

Installation Notes --
I simply downloaded `bash.exe` and other bash-like commands from [SourceForge](http://win-bash.sourceforge.net/) and added the entire downloaded directory to my path.

Comment: In PowerShell, `~` is defined in the `PSProvider`:  `Get-PSProvider -PSProvider FileSystem | % Home`.  However under bash, I'm uncertain how that system interprets it.

Comment: In PowerShell, `~` takes me to the correct place (i.e. `C:\Users\name`), but that doesn't seem to translate to bash.

Comment: I think we'll need more details about **how** you installed bash.exe. Is this [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/wsl/install-win10) or something else?

Comment: Just edited to include this...please advise if not informative enough.

Comment: This story has been asked before. Please check the suggested solutions in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46898841/2166900

Answer (score 0):

Oh, that wont work in bash with your example, you need cut \ if you wanna add a folder this way:

```
export HOME='C:\\Users\\name'
```

But, try this if you are inside a linux environment since c: gets mounted in /mnt by default :

```
export HOME='/mnt/c/users/name'
```

You also can try this with your example if you just running it from powershell:

#### Create a .bashrc file:

```
 C:\Users\USERNAME\.bashrc
```

#### Now add below string to this file:

```
HOME=$PATH:/c/users/name
```

Comment: Thanks. Neither of these worked though.

Comment: Try this: HOME=/c/Users/$USERNAME

Comment: Sorry, neither of these worked either.

Comment: Okey what about:

Set-Variable HOME "C:\Users\usernamehere" -Force
echo $HOME
cd ~

Tried on my machine:
Set-Variable HOME "C:\Users\wuseman\testdir\"
cd $HOME
pwd
C:\Users\wuseman\testdir\

Comment: That doesn't work for me in either Powershell or bash. In powershell it states that my home env is changed (i.e. `echo $HOME` returns the correctly changed dir), but `cd ~` still goes to the original location. I should note that in powershell `cd ~` changes directory to `C:\Users\username`, but in bash it changes directory to `C:`

Comment: Okey, my last idea that must work otherwise something is wrong.

Enter your home dir - 'cd $HOME'  type 'Set-Location ~' when you entered the dir, does '~' point to your $HOME dir now?

Comment: This also does not work. I have a feeling that bash somehow misinterprets where the home directory is. Please note that I am not running Windows Subsystem for Linux, but rather installed `bash.exe` from sourceforge and simply added it to my path (see Installation Notes in edits to original question).

Bash also is not able to find my `.bashrc` file, so I have to explicitly provide that with the `-rcfile` flag and a path to my `.bashrc` file. I'm guessing it looks for that in `C:`.

Comment: @wuseman You cannot set `$HOME` in PowerShell.  It's an automatic (read-only) variable.

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly the `HOME` variable which rules the expansion of `~` in win-bash is not the *bash variable* of this name, but rather the *Windows environment variable*. So, we can change where `~` goes only if we set `HOME` before `bash` is started, e. g. in `cmd` with `set HOME=…`.

Comment: PowerShell syntax: `$Env:HOME = '...'`