# Change Location of global Git Configuration File

Tags: git

Can I change the location of the global Git configuration file from `~/.gitconfig` to some custom location?

For example, to `~/.config/git/.gitconfig`?

Comment: Why would you want to to that? What are you trying to solve?

Comment: I just wanted to organize all my config files under one directory rather than have them all scattered around in my Home directory.

Comment: What I (and apparently many others as well) do is to have my ~/.xxx files as symbolic links. The actual dot-files are elsewhere, in a Git repository. I recently fancied things up a lot and made a Python script that creates the symlinks, which is in https://github.com/chris3torek/scripts (along with some published dot-files, which are not quite the same as my home ones for historic reasons).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing .gitconfig location on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050905/changing-gitconfig-location-on-windows)

Answer (score 4):

From [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES), you can try and set `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`

```
XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config
```

> Second user-specific configuration file.
>   If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is not set or empty, `$HOME/.config/git/config` will be used.
>   Any single-valued variable set in this file will be overwritten by whatever is in `~/.gitconfig`. It is a good idea not to create this file if you sometimes use older versions of Git, as support for this file was added fairly recently.

It does not change the global config, but offers an alternative location.