# Git on Windows 10 Config directory

Tags: git, windows-10

I installed Git 2.28.0 64 bit on windows 10. The default git config is set to my home directory. Since this is a company computer, the HOME is always set to a network folder by Group Policy.

I tryied some suggestions that editing the etc/profile file by setting the HOME variable at the top of the like this:

```
HOME="/c/Users/MyUserName/Documents"
```

This trick did not work. My question is how to change this?

Thanks to a few people suggested this [Changing .gitconfig location on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050905/changing-gitconfig-location-on-windows) but it did not help. I have tried the suggestions (except for the Power Script option, which is not an option in my situation)  there but still did not work.

Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing .gitconfig location on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050905/changing-gitconfig-location-on-windows)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I read that already and tried some of the suggestions except for writing a power shell script to update it dynamically - which is not an option. I just wonder the reason behind making this so difficult to set the config location .... ???

Comment: Does it work if you write `export HOME=foo` instead of just `HOME=foo` in that line?

Comment: What's wrong with having HOME (and in turn `.gitconfig`) set to a network folder?

Comment: @jingx If I am not connected to the company network, then I cannot access HOME directory.

Comment: If you are allowed to change `/etc` (via local sudo probably), you can put the config in `/etc/gitconfig`, or set `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` to some directory, and put the config in `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config.  See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a company computer and can set `HOME` in my user environment variables to any path I want.

That is enough for Git to switch folder.

That would assume the company does not force the environment variable `HOME` itself: on Windows 10, the company generally set `HOMEDRIVE` (not `HOME`) to a network drive.

Comment: My IT is not as nice as yours :)

Comment: @user1941319 Do you mean they are setting `HOME`, not just `HOMEDRIVE`? And you cannot set your own user environment variables? (I am not talking about system environment variables)