# Setting .gitconfig Location

Tags: git

My .gitconfig file was located in a drive that was recently deleted. Now doing any git commits and pushes, I'm noticing my git user name has changed. When trying to add a new global username, I'm presented with the following error:

```
error: could not lock config file H://.gitconfig: Permission denied
```

Would the best course of action would be to recreate a .gitconfig file, place that in the C drive, and tell git to look there for user credentials?

Comment: Would this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/q/4050905/14967413

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing .gitconfig location on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050905/changing-gitconfig-location-on-windows)