# VS Code suddenly uses global .gitconfig at %USERPROFILE%

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am under Win11. Never had a problem using git and VS Code.

## My setup so far

I have defined an environment variable %HOME% where I have my global file `.gitconfig` (including name and email) which is used by `git.exe`. So far this worked flawless  - from terminal, from terminal in VS Code **and** from GUI in VS Code.

## Suddenly...

upon comitting from **GUI** in VS Code, I got error message that name and email are missing. However, everything was fine from terminal (also from terminal in VS Code).

Finally, I found out VS Code is now using / expecting `.gitconfig` at location %USERPROFILE%.

## Questions

- Why is that?
- How can I change ist back? (I simply want that VSCode uses the same settings as `git.exe`.)

## Two current workarounds

1. Set %HOME% = %USERPROFILE% and move my `.gitconfig` (not what I want)
2. Disable setting `Require Git User Config` in VS Code. But is this really the reason?

### Edit 2023-03-01:

In my opinion, this is not a problem with Git, but with VS Code. Git behaves as usual, but VS Code suddenly requires a `.gitignore` in a different location. I don't understand why VS Code cares about this at all. I always understood the Git GUI in VS Code as just a way to save me typing in the command line, but now that doesn't seem to be the case anymore.

Here's an example: Clicking "commit" with the message "My message" does not translate directly into the

`git commit -m "My message"`

command, but into something else...

Comment: you want `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`

Comment: Not a Windows user so can't give definitive suggestion but if it were me I'd do a different workaround: instead of moving `.gitconfig` I'd symlink it to the `USERPROFILE` directory.

Comment: Since 2.34.1 (maybe earlier), you need to use `GIT_CONFIG_GLOBAL`, not `HOME` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4050905/changing-gitconfig-location-on-windows/70345376#70345376)